# NoSQL - how to implement autosuggest and best matches properly?

Tags: search, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, autosuggest, search-suggestion

We're building a database of cars and their properties, supposed to be stored in a DynamoDB.

Creating a `cars` table and filling it with objects that has properties like `brand`, `model`, `year` etc is easy.

But we also want a few other features en the admin interface:

**Suggestions when typing**

When creating a car, it should suggest brand and model from existing cars, when typing in the field.

Should we then maintain a list of brands and models in another table, and make a query to that table, when the user types?

Or is it good enough to query the "rich" table of car definitions, and get all values for `brand`, all `model` values where `brand` has a certain value, etc? My first thought is that it would be a heavy operation and we'd want a separate index of cars and models. But I'm not a NoSQL expert...

**Best matches**

When enrolling a new car in our system we want to use use an existing defined car as a reference if possible.

So when the user has typed in a brand, model, year etc we want to show a few options of the best matches - we can accept that they year etc. is different, but want the best matches first.

What is the best way to do matches like this on data in a NoSQL database? Any links to tools, concepts etc. will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dynamodb (all nosql), the less you create tables the best is your architecture (this is one of the main reason we use nosql), so no need of a new table, just add a new attribute and fill it with the searchable data you want, just have in mind that querying by dynamodb is case sensitive and you only can use the ***begins_with*** or the ***contains*** function to query data

**The cons are :**

1. You will use lot of reading capacity unit
2. You have to manage the capital letters
3. You have to fabric at each creation the searchable attribute

The solution I suggest is using aws cloudsearch, which gives an out of the boxes suggester, you will will have better results and give a better user experience, the indexation in cloudsearch is automatic each time you have a new item, but be aware of the pricing,  however they will give you 30 day for free

Comment: Yes I can see that cloudsearch use an EC2 instance - we wanted to avoid having servers at all, and have done well so far. But it's only 5$/month...

Anyway, the mentioned system will only be used by administrative staff, and will (in the beginning) have only a few lookups etc. a day, so the extended usage of dynamo shouldn't be a problem, I think? But I don't want to waste a lot of time implementing an inefficient solution if it's faster/easier to implement with cloudsearch or elasticsearch. 

I wonder why AWS don't offer this as a "pay per use" service instead of EC2?

Comment: Yep, as you said,  more efficient faster, and cost less time to deploy,  but a little bit expensive,  so it's up to you